# Google Data Studio pie chart JSON format?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm trying to create a Pie Chart in Google Looker Studio (previously called Google Data Studio) from my own JSON community connector data, but I can't find any information on the format it needs to be.

I made an assumption that it would be a Google Pie chart: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

So I tested a JSON object key like this.

```
"totalIncomePie": [
    ["Income type", "Income"],
    ["Test 1", 30],
    ["Test 2", 60]
  ]
```

That said the data wasn't formatted correctly, which makes sense as there's no setType(types.JSON), so not sure I can use that approach either.

I might try JSON.stringify the whole object key, and see if that gets recognised with types.TEXT.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We need more information about your code. Firstly, notice that Community Connectors are not designed for a specific type of chart, so if it is a table or a pie chart, it doesn't matter. Secondly, your example seems odd to me. In community connectors, the fields are provided by a method and the values by other method. In your example it seems both are in the same structure, which doesn't make much sense for me.

Comment: Do you think if I split out the fields and the values into two separate JSON methods then I may be able to plug it into a Data Studio pie?

Comment: Sure you can. But not in any format, the response JSON must be correctly formatted according to the Community Connector documentation.

Comment: I haven't seen any Community Connector documentation on the format of JSON in custom pie charts. Which is kinda my originally question. Do you have a link?

Comment: Firstly, forget about pie charts. The type of chart has NOTHING to do with your community connector development. If your connector works for a table it SHOULD work for a pie chart or any other visual. Now that you know this, try the tutorial. It contains a step-by-step guide on how to create a community connector: https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/connector/build Also, the result that each function should return (getData, getSchema, etc) you can see in the function documentation (example for getData: https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/connector/reference#getdata )

Answer (score -1):

**Data Studio** offers no direct connection with JSON files or APIs, and the manual processes for getting your JSON data into Data Studio is, in one word, convoluted. Luckily you have several third-party platform options which can integrate your JSON data quickly, without the usual pain.

Comment: Hi Omar. I've built my own JSON community connector, as the others didn't do exactly what I wanted. My question is what format the JSON needs to be to provide data for a Data Studio Pie.

Comment: @OmarAlsulaymi his question clearly states he is using a Community Connector. Reading from JSON API sources is the most common example for this kind of connector.